# Unable to start jboss-as-7.1.1.Final with JDK 8 on Windows 8.1 command prompt

Tags: java-8, windows-8.1, jboss7.x

Using standalone.bat, in the command prompt following is shown:

```
D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms
64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.prefe
rIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=stan
dalone.xml  "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log"  "-Dlogging.configuration=file:D:\jboss-as
-7.1.1.Final\standalone/configuration/logging.properties"     -jar "D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar"     -mp "D:\jboss-a
s-7.1.1.Final\modules"     -jaxpmodule "javax.xml.jaxp-provider"      org.jboss.as.standalone     -Djboss.home.dir="D:\jboss-as-7.
1.1.Final"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
01:43:23,386 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
01:43:23,558 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
01:43:23,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
01:43:24,949 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
01:43:24,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
01:43:24,964 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
01:43:24,995 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
01:43:25,027 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
01:43:25,058 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsys
tem.
01:43:25,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
01:43:25,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
01:43:25,058 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
01:43:25,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.F
inal)
01:43:25,183 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
01:43:25,183 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
01:43:25,292 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
01:43:25,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-co
mpliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
01:43:26,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]

01:43:26,042 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
01:43:26,011 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF S
erver 4.0.2.GA
01:43:26,870 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-
8080
01:43:30,917 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jb
oss/datasources/ExampleDS]
```

I have set the JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java` and 
JBOSS_HOME to `D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final`

PATH includes `C:\Windows\System32`. Have I missed something?

The above lines do not include the message "Brontes started". And trying to access the url http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/ gives HTTP 404 ERROR "The webpage cannot be found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too came across this issue. Firstly I downgraded to JDK 1.7 and it happened to work smoothly but as I wanted to work on JDK 1.8, I downloaded [WildFly 10](http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.0.0.Final/wildfly-10.0.0.Final.zip) former JBossAS.

It works smoothly without any compatibility issues.

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/04/22/jboss_as_becomes_wildfly/

Answer (score 8):

JBoss AS 7 doesn't work on JDK8.

Either upgrade AS to version WildFly 8 or 9. or use JDK7.

For more details on that see my post on jboss.org [forums](https://developer.jboss.org/message/926279#926279)