# How do I get Spring Boot Security and JBoss 7.1 to play nicely with each other?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

Versions:

JBoss: 7.1
Spring Boot: 1.4.1.RELEASE

Starting a project from scratch and following the directions for securing a spring-boot app from here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/, I get an application quick and easy that runs from `gradle clean bootRun`.

But, when I build with `gradle clean war` and deploy to a JBoss 7.1 server, during startup it fails with the following:

```
2016-09-24 18:01:37,783 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (MSC service thread 1-10)  | Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:80) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-fas.jar:fas-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-fas.jar:fas-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-fas.jar:fas-4]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:91) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
... 11 more
```

I've been digging on this thing for a couple weeks and trying to attack it from a number of angles. I get a similar error when I skip the WebSecurity class together and instead do a @ImportResource("classpath:security-context.xml) (from another working project).  With a bit of tinkering I get it to behave again for `gradle bootRun` but deploying it to JBoss results in the same error.

TIA.

Significant code sections:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

...

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5')

    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

DemoApplication:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SnapshotApiDemoApplication.class);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SnapshotApiDemoApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
    application:
      name: snapshot
      debug: true

  server:
    version: UNKNOWN
    context-path: /
```

application.properties:

```
logger.level=DEBUG
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE

handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush
handler.CONSOLE.level=INFO
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=PATTERN

handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler
handler.FILE.level=INFO
handler.FILE.properties=autoFlush,fileName
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=demo.log
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN

formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using JDK 1.8 for your SpringBoot app.

JBoss AS 7 doesn't work on JDK8.

See [Unable to start jboss-as-7.1.1.Final on Windows 8.1 command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194474/unable-to-start-jboss-as-7-1-1-final-on-windows-8-1-command-prompt)

Comment: Hmm. Specifically I'm running JBoss 7.1.2 and I have that running on an environment using Java 1.8 (b101). The application seems to run otherwise. I would suspect other applications would fail within the JVM but no one else is complaining... Thoughts?

Comment: Also, note, I rebuilt the app indicating sourceCompatibility = 1.7 &
targetCompatibility = 1.7 in the build.gradle file with no apparent impact to the error as it remains.

Comment: So I found another box where I had JBoss 7.1.2 running and Java version 1.7 (b79) running the server.  Deployed the app and got the same stack trace: 

 Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:80) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]

I agree, it looks like a versioning issue but not sure which.