# JBoss eap 7.0.0 UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I have some problems when deploying my app with JBoss eap 7.0.0

The app is compiled using Java 1.8 revision 121, and also the JBoss is launched with the same JDK.

The error is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jboss/modules/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Does anybody have some information about what's happening? It seems like the error is in a module that is not from the application, but from any JBoss library (org/jboss/modules/Main)

Comment: are you running in eclipse/intellij? maybe your java there is connected to old jdk

Comment: I'm running it in an standalone process, not within Eclipse. When JBoss starts, it shows the Java version  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java

Comment: from previous post there's an issue with JBOSS 7 and Java 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194474/unable-to-start-jboss-as-7-1-1-final-with-jdk-8-on-windows-8-1-command-prompt

Comment: That question is for JBoss AS 7 this is for JBoss EAP 7 which requires Java 8.

Comment: Can you post the top part of the console output where it prints the `JAVA_HOME`? 52 is Java 8 so the only way it would be an issue is if it's picking up the wrong `java` command.

Comment: Please, read the question and the previous answers... It is launched using Java 1.8, revision 121. The top part of the console prints "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java". Thanks for your answers...

Comment: I saw that, but the error definitely means it's not finding the correct JDK version. Is this a standalone or domain server?

Comment: Have you checked what is set for `JAVA_HOME` in your `<jboss_home>/bin/standalone.conf.bat` file? Is it different than you are using to compile your java classes?