# Decorators not loading in JBOSS 7 and jdk8

Tags: jboss

I have following decorators.xml file under WEB-INF folder

```
<decorators>
    <decorator name="mydecorator" page="/WEB-INF/jsp/decorators/decorator.jsp">
        <pattern>/secure/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="unsecurepages" page="/WEB-INF/jsp/decorators/unsecuredecorator.jsp">
        <pattern>/*.htm</pattern>
    </decorator>

</decorators>
```

I have both JSP files in repective locations as well..   While hitting main PAGE url this two pages should be loaded and dispalyed. Its working well with JBOSS 5 and JRE 6..Now i  am migraating app to Jboss 7 and JDK 8 .. Also am using sitemesh as below from web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Using PageFilter from jar sitemesh-2.5-atlassian-11.jar.   Now the issue is not loading with  JBOSS 7.  need help

Answer (score 0):

Jboss7 is not compatible with java8. 
I had some other issues running Jboss7 with java8 for this I downgraded to java7.

See also:

- [Unable to start jboss-as-7.1.1.Final with JDK 8 on Windows 8.1 command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194474/unable-to-start-jboss-as-7-1-1-final-with-jdk-8-on-windows-8-1-command-prompt)
- [Run JBoss 7.1 on Java 8](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/240679)

Answer (score 0):

```
add <meta name="decorator" content="main" /> between<HEAD> and <TITLE>
```

will fixing this problem